# Interactivity between ReMesh modifiers that are on two different objects

Tags: mesh, topology, remesh

I was watching this tutorial where the instructor has two objects with what looks to be the ReMesh modifier on them, and he’s grabbing one of them on the mouse cursor and moving it around so that its mesh intersects with the other object, and the modifier seems to automatically create mesh to connect the two objects at their intersection in real time
[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]
[image: screenshot3]
I wonder how this is done? When I try to do the same thing the mesh does not connect at all, and the two objects just have the modifier effect on themselves separately. If I join these objects, the mesh does connect and get re-meshed together, but then I’m not able to see how it looks in real time in the view port (I’d have to link select one object in Edit Mode to move them around and you can only see the results in Object Mode). The tutorial shows that the instructor is doing it entirely in Object Mode also.

Or am I wrong in assuming that this is the ReMesh modifier? I just need to do the same thing no matter what method

Comment: Given screens show Meatball objects ...

Comment: I did hear him mention Metaball but he didn’t go into details (was kind of just talking about how to change our ways of thinking to do things faster and stuff). I’m gonna go have a look

Comment: You’re right, that’s totally it, thanks! Should I close the question? (Not sure about the customs of stackexchange…)

Comment: If you have privilege to Delete ... yes of course you can :) No problem.

Comment: Now that you have answered I will not delete it. I just thought it would be rude to delete it after receiving any response including comment (I was thinking because i was mistaking the screenshots for remesh i could be wasting people’s time)

Comment: I'm still OK with deleting the Q if you want I created the answer just to give you faster illustration of mesh version, but as mentioned for quick sketch Metaballs are the way to go for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given screens show **Metaball** objects ...

---

If you want to do something similar with **Mesh** use *Boolean* and *Remesh* modifier (works in some cases). Here two Cube objects ...

[image]

[image]

[image]

But speaking to effectivity Metaballs works faster and better in transitions for sketching base shape, that your tutorial was meant to be.

Comment: So in order for the remesh modifier to interact between objects i need to also have a boolean modifier on it?

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I’m already gonna look at both Metaballs and your additional method. I will try these when I get back and in front of my computer later!

Comment: @vklidu If I may, I edited your meatball to a metaball :)

Comment: Check blend file ... probably better than my bad thousands English words :) @GorgonBrinkmann +1 Thank you (my dictionary intervention, weather condition, ... :)

Comment: Worked, thank you